# How to Add new data to an existing Index in Vector Search vertex AI using python library

Tags: google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-ai-platform, vertex-ai-search

I am familiar with vectordbs like weaviate and pinecone, and trying to migrate my vectors to gcp.
I have uploaded data to a bucket, created index with it and deployed an endpoint using python and following this documentation [Vector Search Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/vector-search/quickstart).Querying works fine for the index.

Now I want to add new data to the same index, (batch upsertion or equivalent in weaviate or pinecone), which as far as i understand can be done via GUI by doing batch update in the edit Index option, but I am unable to figure out how can i achieve it with python client.

I apologise if this is stupid question, been trying to figure out for a while now, and docs are confusing me more than helping.

I looked at [update and rebuild Index](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/vector-search/update-rebuild-index#console) and [updateIndex](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest/google.cloud.aiplatform_v1.services.index_service.IndexServiceClient#google_cloud_aiplatform_v1_services_index_service_IndexServiceClient_update_index), but am unable to figure out if this creates entire index from scratch with the new data or upserts them like weaviate or pinecone.

Answer (score 0):

A staff answered on google cloud forum, [here](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/AI-ML/Adding-data-to-Vector-Search-Index/td-p/715038)

> Welcome and thank you for reaching out to our community.
> I believe both functionalities do not have batch data processing (upserting).
> The update index updates the metadata associated with the index, like description, labels, or settings while the actual data content (vectors and document IDs) remains untouched
> The rebuild index rebuilds the entire index from scratch, deleting all existing data in the index then recreates it using the data provided in the request
> I hope I was able to provide you with useful insights.

However I do think its possible, just not with aiplatform as of now (march 2024), There's a method for IndexService in aiplatformv1, not in aiplatform.

Someone pointed this out in .NET, in another reply to the staff:

> Hey, not sure about the naming for Python but in .NET there is a class [IndexServiceClient](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1/latest/Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1.IndexServiceClient#Google_Cloud_AIPlatform_V1_IndexServiceClient_UpsertDatapoints_Google_Cloud_AIPlatform_V1_UpsertDatapointsRequest_Google_Api_Gax_Grpc_CallSettings_) that has all methods to manage the index. And it has a method [UpsertDatapoints](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1/latest/Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1.UpsertDatapointsRequest) that processes a [UpsertDatapointsRequest](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1/latest/Google.Cloud.AIPlatform.V1.UpsertDatapointsRequest) which represents batch of vectors.